# Cannot connect to MYSQL docker container

Tags: mysql, docker

I have created an image of a MySQL database and run it in a container. I would like it on ports **3406/3407**, so I call the **docker run** command like this :

```
docker run -d -p 3406:3407 --name db ollyw123/shape-shop-db:latest
```

If I look at my containers it looks like this :

```
C:\Users\owatkins.ext>docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                              COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                         NAMES
b907f878f82b        ollyw123/shape-shop-db:latest                                      "docker-entrypoint.s…"   12 minutes ago      Up 12 minutes       3306/tcp, 33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3406->3407/tcp   db
```

I would very much like to connect to my database now but I can't seem to get my URL working.

This is what my URL looks like :

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3406/db
```

Comment: Did you reconfigure the database port used by the MySQL container to be `3407`? Otherwise, I would expect `docker run ... -p 3406:3306 ...`.

Comment: i was just experimenting with different port numbers. I know 3306/7 is somehow special for MYSql but i just wanted to try it with different port numbers

Comment: So use `.. 3406:3306` as @Turing85 said.. 
And check how ports in docker works: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/

Comment: And maybe read an introduction on ports in general. Normally, an application does not "magically open ports", but has well-defined ports, and each port has a clear function.

Comment: ok, i think i will . thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default port of mysql is `3306` not `3407`, so you should use port-forwarding with `3306`

- `docker run -d -p 3406:3306 --name db ollyw123/shape-shop-db:latest`